# Inserir uma Div de uma outra página

Tags: php, html, html5

Eu estou tentando pegar uma `DIV` desta [página](http://pipocaplayfm.com/artist/5216/Calvin+Harris) .

A `DIV` tem o nome de `.similar-artists`. Quero jogar na `DIV` chamada `#rock`, porém não funciona nada. Abaixo o código:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 
 $("#rock").load("http://pipocaplayfm.com/artist/5216/Calvin+Harris .similar-artists ");
 
  });
 
</script>

</head>
<body>
 
<div id="rock">
 
</div>
   
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Você está desenvolvendo um site como página estática, utilizando APENAS HTML ou está desenvolvendo dinamicamente, com JavaEE, PHP, JavaScript?

Comment: @TiagoBoeing dinamicamente com javascript e php.
eu só preciso entender como eu faço isso funcionar  
$("#div1").load("demo_test.txt #p1");   como no link : https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_load.asp

Comment: Você consegue isso usando o próprio PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tenta dessa maneira..

```js
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://pipocaplayfm.com/artist/5216/Calvin+Harris',
    success: function(res){
                        $(res.responseText).find('.similar-artists')each(function(){
            $('#app').append($(this).html())
        
        });
    }
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app"></div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: a parte do Ajax eu coloco tudo na mesma página ?
eu copiei e colei na minha pagina aqui e apenas quando eu atualizo mostra o codigo do ajax e nao o conteudo.  preciso colocar algo a mais ou fazer ?

Comment: fiz tudo como se encontra , mas nao funciona

Comment: Não é possível puxar conteúdo de outro site via Ajax devido ao CORS.

Comment: @jhonatansantos Testei aqui e foi como o amigo a cima falou, o site está bloqueando, então devido ao `CORS`, não é possivel puxar o conteudo.

Comment: @RafaelAugusto existe alguma maneira de eu desabilitar esse CORS que vc citou ??